# i have a problem "out_of_range at memory location" in c++

Tags: c++, string

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string pumbaTheString;
    getline(cin, pumbaTheString);
    int indexs[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        indexs[i] = pumbaTheString.find(" ");
        pumbaTheString.replace(indexs[i], 1, "*");
    }
    cout << pumbaTheString << endl;
    pumbaTheString.replace(indexs[2] + 1, (pumbaTheString.length() - indexs[2]), "#!!@1234");
    cout << pumbaTheString<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; ++i)
    {
        pumbaTheString =  pumbaTheString.substr((indexs[i] - indexs[i - 1]), pumbaTheString.length());//here its did the problem

        cout << pumbaTheString << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

//Unhandled exception at 0x75CCAD12 in Project1.exe:
// Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0073F614. occurred

Comment: `indexs[i - 1]` for `i=0` will be `indexs[-1]` so its out of range

Comment: Besides the above mentioned index problem (which won't directly result in an `out_of_range` exception, but rather *undefined behavior*, which of course could lead to an exception further down the road, like if you're using an indeterminate value as a string index) are you sure that all your string manipulation will work? That there are at least three spaces in the input? That all indexes you save in your array are valid? What is the *exact* input when you get the exception?

Comment: And please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Don't use raw arrays in C++, use at least `std::array` (or possible `std::vector`) which both provide out of bounds checks in debug builds.

Comment: On a high-level, what is this code supposed to be do?  I'm sure there are better / easier / less error-prone ways of accomplishing whatever you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

at first iteration of the `for` loop you are trying to get `indexs[i - 1] == indexs[-1]` element.Array indexes are starting from 0 and negative values are forbidden. You need to add some special handling for the first iteration like:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; ++i)
    {   
    if(i == 0)
    {
        // special handling
    }
    else
    {
        pumbaTheString =  pumbaTheString.substr((indexs[i] - indexs[i - 1]), pumbaTheString.length());//here its did the problem
    }
    cout << pumbaTheString << endl;
}
```